# How can I export specific rows using Python and SQL from pgAdmin table?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, pgadmin

How can I export specific rows using Python and SQL from pgAdmin table ?
For example , I have one export button in my python file, I'm using tkinter there.
When I click button it needs to be exported from pgAdmin table rows between 1000 to 2000 in excel format.

Please , help me.

Comment: pgAdmin is not a database.  It is just another client.  Does this question relate to pgAdmin at all?

Comment: I'm a pgAdmin developer/hacker. To be frank, I didn't understand what exactly is the question.